# Show image in SecondViewController when button is clicked in FirstViewController

Tags: ios, delegates, uiimageview

After several attempts I do not succeed to understand were is the error and why the image doesn't appear...

myProtocol.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

-(UIImage *)transferImage; 

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIView *view;
} 

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender; 

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h" 
#import "SecondViewController.h" 
#import "myProtocol.h"

@interface ViewController () 

@end 

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"]];
    [view addSubview:_imageView]; NSLog(@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png");
}

-(UIImage *)transferImage
{
    NSLog(@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"); 
    return _imageView.image;
} 

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender 
{    
    SecondViewController *secClass = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [secClass setImageName:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
} 

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import "myProtocol.h" 
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController <myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate> 
{
    UIView *secondView; IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage; id <myProtocol> myDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *myImage;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *transferImage;
@property(nonatomic,assign) id delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *imageName;

-(void)callTransfer; 

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "myProtocol.h" 

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end 

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate, myImage, transferImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization 
    } 

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [secondView addSubview:myImage];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
}

-(void)callTransfer
{
    myImage.image=[delegate performSelector:@selector(transferImage)];
    myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myImage.image);
    NSLog(@"I am in call transfer");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please format your code, it is terrible to read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are not going to reuse a class, then I would not suggest using delegates, as there are other ways to pass data between 2 classes.

It seems you are trying to pass an UIImage from the First to the Second ViewController.
So make your life easier:

```
- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender 
{    
    SecondViewController *secClass = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secClass.transferImage = self.imageView.image;
    [secClass.myImage setImage:self.imageView.image];
    [secClass setImageName:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];
}
```

and voila, your second View controller, has the UIImage pointer in the transferImage variable...

Comment: If I use "secClass.myImage = self.imageView.image;" the error is generated:                                                   Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImageView *' from 'UIImage *'

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that the `myImage` was a UIImageView and not an image. You should use proper naming conventions for your variables. If it's a UIImageView, use something like myImageView and not myImage, as someone that sees a variable named myImage, would expect that this variable is an UIImage and not an UIImageView. I have now updated my code, which means your transferImage variable will now have the pointer of the UIImage

Comment: The error is disappeared, but I don't understand because the image in the SecondViewController of the UIImageView does not appear inside...

Comment: Well you need to assign the UIImage to the UIImageView too. See my code edit again

Comment: You could help me to assign the UIImage to the UIImageView? Thx and excuse for my incompetency.

Comment: I have already edited the answer and am assigning it to your imageview... Remove your assignment in the viewWillAppear delegate

Comment: I do not understand as I must modify...

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
}